# java.util.NoSuchElementException: No line found exception when using scanner inside the loop

Tags: java, exception

I have a requirement of taking input inside a loop but getting an issue saying such as `NoSuchElementException`. Not really sure about the issue.

To give some information about my requirement, I have to perform a function if the user types `yes` continuously until the user type `no`.

Code:

```
    // Toppings
    while(true) {
      Scanner st = new Scanner(System.in);
      System.out.println("Do you need to add more toppings: (yes/no)");
      String decision = st.nextLine();

      if (decision.equals("yes")) {
        cake = toppingOption(cake);
      } else if (decision.equals("no")) {
        st.close();
        break;
      } else {
        System.out.println("Wrong input, type (yes/no)");
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have more than one Scanner that you close, which closes the underlying `InputStream`, therefore another `Scanner` can no longer read from the same `InputStream` and a `NoSuchElementException` results.

Move st out of while loop

```
Scanner st = new Scanner(System.in);
// Toppings
    while(true) {

      System.out.println("Do you need to add more toppings:(yes/no)");
      String decision = st.nextLine();

      if(decision.equals("yes")) {
        cake = toppingOption(cake);
      } 
      else if(decision.equals("no")) {
        st.close();
        break;
      }
      else {
        System.out.println("Wrong input, type (yes/no)");
      }
    }
```

Comment: Although a correct suggestion, this cannot be the problem. Only one scanner is closed in this code!

Comment: @hien-nguyen yes your suggestion is the problem, this is just a part of the code, inside the toppingOption method I have another scanner object which I close, sorry for not mentioning that. Thanks again.

Answer (score -1):

My question is incomplete, inside the `toppingOptions` function I have another scanner object which I close, so after I remove the scanner objects close this work.